# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity Method not found

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I have this error in my Spring Boot application. I've looked at similar posts and I'm not using RestEasyClient. How can I determine this error's root cause?

```java
ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity(java.lang.Class)'
```

Comment: Please post your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is jsr311-api when I exclude this from my pom,problem is resolved

```
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
```